# How do check the contents of a List using an if statement in python

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I am new to python, I have written the following code but it will not reduce the score if B is entered, it increases the score by 1 if How, Hi etc are entered but not it 8 is entered and does not reduce the score if B is entered.  Can anyone help.

grid=[8,"B","How", "Hi", "Hey", "How are you doing", "How's it going", "How", "Hello"]

```
def Play():   
    count=0      
    score=0    
    while (count<11):
        I=input("Enter your guess")
        if I in grid:
           score+=1
           print("Your score is:", score)
        elif I in grid == "B":
           score=0
           print("Your score is:",score)
        else:
           print("I don't understand")
        count+=1
```

Comment: `elif I in grid == "B":` doesn't make sense. Take B out of grid and put it in a different list. Otherwise you need `elif I in grid and I == 'B':` or something similar, which is counter-intuitive as a setup.

Comment: `I in grid` returns a `bool`. You're asking "If I is in grid..." (which returns `True` or `False`) "is equal to the letter B, do this". `True` and `False` won't be equal to the letter B.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` stores input as a string. Therefore, if the user enters `8`, it will be stored as `"8"`. `"8"` is not the same as `8`, so `if I in grid` will evaluate to `False`. To solve this, you can change `8` to `"8"` in the list, or add `elif I == "8":`

`elif I in grid == "B":` will never evaluate as true. This is because you are checking `(I in grid) == ("B")`. `I in grid` will in always be `True` or `False`, so you are comparing `"B"` with a boolean, which is always `False`.

An easier way to accomplish this is to change `8` to `"8"` in `grid:

```
grid=["8","B","How", "Hi", "Hey", "How are you doing", "How's it going", "How", "Hello"]
```

And check if `I == "B"` in the first `if` statement:

```
if I in grid:
    if I == "B":
        score=0
    else:
        score+=1
    print("Your score is:",score)
else:
    print("I don't understand")
```

Comment: There was one thing we both haven't commented on, which might be worth noting. `if I in grid:` is `True` even for `"B"` so `elif I in grid == "B":` is never even evaluated anyway in the OP's approach since it breaks out at the first `True` evaluation.